# Don't work deleting coin because old value in setInterval method react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, closures

I want delete value in `removeCurrency` method. The value is being deleted but after 2-3 seconds value is returned. This is hapenning when `fetchData` method is start. In method `fetchData` value `cryptoCurrency` is old.

````
export function Crypto(props: CryptoProps){
    const [cryptoCurriensies, setCryptoCurriensies] = useState<Coin[]>([ {usd: null, name: 'LUNA'}, {usd: null, name: 'BNB'}, {usd: null, name: 'XRP'}]);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState<number| undefined>(undefined)

   async function removeCurrency(cryptoName: string){
        let coins = [...cryptoCurriensies];
        let filteredCoins = coins.filter(coin => coin.name !== cryptoName)
        setCryptoCurriensies(filteredCoins);
    }

     useEffect(() => {
         fetchData();
        let intervalId = window.setInterval(() => fetchData(), 5000);
        return () => {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }
    , [cryptoCurriensies]);

     async function fetchData() {
        try {
            const coins = await Promise.all(
                cryptoCurriensies.map(async (coin) => {
                const res = await fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${coin.name}&tsyms=USD&api_key=${API_KEY}`);
                const usd = await res.json();
                let price = Number(usd.USD);
                return { ...coin, usd: price };
              })
            );
            setCryptoCurriensies([...coins])
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
    } 

    function setCrypto(coins: Coin[]){
        setCryptoCurriensies(coins);
    }

    const add = (name: string) => {
        fetch(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${name}&tsyms=USD&api_key=${API_KEY}`, { mode: 'cors' })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    if (result.Response === 'Error') {
                        addError(name, result.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                     addNameToState(name);
                },
                (error) => {
                    addError(name, error);
                }
            )
    }

    function addNameToState(name: string) {
        let coins = [...cryptoCurriensies, {name: name, usd: null}];
        setCryptoCurriensies(coins);
    }

    function addError(name: string, error: string) {
        setError(`Error occurred: not found crypto with name = ${name} in base ` + error)
    }

    function clearMessage(){
        setError('');
    }

        return <div className="crypto">
            <h1 className="header">CryptoMoney</h1>
            <CryptoList cryptoCurrensies={cryptoCurriensies} removeCurrency={removeCurrency} setCoins={setCrypto}/>
            <CryptoInput add={add} />
            <Modal message={error} title={'Error'} clearMessage={clearMessage} />
        </div>
}
}```
````

Comment: I'm a React noob, but `setCryptoCurriensies` can also accept a function, and that function accepts the updated value. Change the part in `fetchData` to something like `setCryptoCurriensies(newCoins => newCoins.map(async (coin) => { . . . })`.

Comment: It seems you are asking about two different issues. Is the issue with removing a currency in the `removeCurrency` function? Is the issue with the `fetchData` interval? Can you clarify more specifically the issue and what the expected behavior should be? What are your steps to reproduce this issue? Can you walk us through exact reproduction steps?

Comment: Removing work correct but  function setCryptoCurriensies async and fetchData get old value cryptoCurrencies. I tried delete setInterval function and add new but it doesn't work. Function setInterval get old values. To reproduction problems I delete cryptoCurrency and set breakpoint in fetchData - values old